# simple app for monitoring server log?

Tags: linux

At the moment I browse my logs from the server manually. I'm thinking about a dedicated open-source app for it, like Logwatch. I want access to a panel or email report with basic information, such as who is trying to connect to my server on which port, attempts to DDOS, etc.
Which app is best for it, or maybe it would be better to write a bash script for it?

I want a simple solution configuration, like Grafana plus Prometheus, which is too complicated for me at the moment.

Comment: Ask here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/   And be modest, ask for sample app which make few things. Or complex one which make complex things

Answer (score 0):

There are tools available, but unless you go for something complicated like ELK or Loki (where you need to spend lots of time thinking about how to manage and present your data) the simpler solutions all require you to think about what you want to capture.